# Is there a way to select any content after a certain class in css?

Tags: html, css

Using the following HTML examples:

```
<!-- Example 1 --->
<span class='my-class'>Content</span>
Some more content.

<!-- Example 2 --->
<div class='my-class'>Content</div>
Some more content.

<!-- Example 3 --->
<p class='my-class'>Content</p>
Some more content.
```

Is there any way to select the "Some more content." part of the examples in CSS without altering the code? The goal behind all of this would to to avoid line breaks after the "my-class" element.

I know that there are solutions doing this by simply adding a container around the class element and the following content but again, I am looking for a solution using this exact code. Is that possible?

Comment: Just wondering, does this piece of code have the same parent container? Do you need to target those `Some more content` all together or separately?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "avoid line breaks"? Do you want the text "Some more content" to display to the right of the my-class elements? If so, there are several CSS-only possibilities. The current answers assume you want to format the text "Some more content" itself.

Comment: @Speir All elements have the same parent container and I would like to target all of them together.

Comment: @MrLister If the parent element is not wide enough a line break will be made before the "Some more content". I am basically looking for a way to connect the my-class elements to the "Some more content" without adding additional elements.

Comment: @Dennis check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

```js
$(".my-class").each(function(e){
 console.log($(this)[0].nextSibling.textContent)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Example 1 --->
<span class='my-class'>Content</span>
Some more content.

<!-- Example 2 --->
<div class='my-class'>Content</div>
Some more content.

<!-- Example 3 --->
<p class='my-class'>Content</p>
Some more content.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my many years of CSS work, the short answer is no. I think you can only do it by adding some sort of container, though it doesn't have to be around both elements like you indicated wanting to avoid ... you could of course just wrap it around the loose text. But I'm sure you already knew that.

Not knowing anything else about it, the only way I can think of is to target the loose text with a higher DOM element, like , then overwrite the class-specific text. I'm guessing that you already know how to do this and that it probably doesn't help, but here's a snippet any way for illustration's sake:

```css
body {
  color: red;
  }
  
.my-class {
  color: black;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<!-- Example 1 --->
<span class='my-class'>Content</span>
Some more content.

<!-- Example 2 --->
<div class='my-class'>Content</div>
Some more content.

<!-- Example 3 --->
<p class='my-class'>Content</p>
Some more content.

</body>
</html>
```